# How to fix P0302 and P0401 error codes for Lincoln Town Car 2001?

Tags: lincoln

I have 2001 model Lincoln Town Car with 4.6L engine. It shows error codes P0302 and P0401. I know little about cars. Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it. Thanks in advance for your answers!